# does Skype use the same password for my Skype name and my Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords, skype, microsoft-account

AFAIK Skype is now owned by Microsoft.

When i log on with my Microsoft account, my Microsoft account password works.

When i log on with my Skype name, my Microsoft account password does not work.

My Skype name in the upper left corner of the Windows Desktop version is two words.

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10858/what-is-a-skype-name-and-how-do-i-find-mine claims:
"Your Skype Name can be between 6 and 32 characters. It starts with a letter, and *can contain only letters, numbers and the following punctuation marks*:
 --   Full stop .
 --   Comma ,
 --   Dash -
 --   Underscore _
Once you've created a Skype Name, you can't change it."

Anyone have any idea as to what is the cause of the problem?

-- the space in my Skype name?
-- a different password from my Microsoft account?

Comment: Do you have two separate accounts? E.g you created a Skype account before linking it to/creating with your Microsoft account?

Comment: Also, it may be because your skype name is your real name. I think they mean your skype username.

Comment: @awesomebing1 -- i created the Skype account after i created the Microsoft account; also, i have a totally different Skype account and when i connect both, it sees my Skype user as two words ... likewise, at the support link above, when i look in the upper left hand corner, i see two words ... i even tried concatenating the two words with a period but that did not work for me -- for that reason, i wonder whether there is a different password for logging on with one's Skype name -- FWIW, my best guess is that the same password should work for either way of logging on.

Comment: I would guess that that is your real name, and you need to find your username. Otherwise, I can't help you :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is the answer to my question.

*mea culpa* i failed to read [What is a Skype Name, and how do I find mine?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10858/what-is-a-skype-name-and-how-do-i-find-mine) with sufficient care.  The text could be written better imho.

"Your **Skype Name** is a *unique user name* that *many* people use to sign in to Skype.

You created one *when you first signed up* for your Skype account.
     --   *turns out i did not*   --

You may also use a **Microsoft account** to sign into Skype,
 which is an email address; *if you do, you won’t have a Skype Name*."

so, according to Skype, one has either a Skype Name or a Microsoft account, but NOT both for the *same* Skype account.

This also explains why my name shows up as two words, i.e., it's a name but not a Skype name.

The example from the Skype website is misleading because it shows a name with a space:
    [image: Skype's help image]

The wording associated with the above image is "Your Skype Name is located in your profile. After signing in, click your name at the top-left corner of the screen".

Below the above image, i saw "Your profile will appear and your Skype Name will be listed under your name".

What is saw was:
    -- my Microsoft account e-mail address
    -- live.firstname.lastname

This was for me confusing because i did not choose "live.firstname.lastname"

One more point, via Skype, i can search for "firstname lastname" without the space and it finds me.

Note:  even though "live.firstname.lastname" is shown under profile, it appears that "live.firstname.lastname" can not be used to sign in.

Comment: Yes;  Microsoft discontinued Skype username awhile ago and went to a unified Microsoft Account.  If you had a Skype name you could ( and still can ) link that username to your Microsoft Account but only the Microsoft Account is linked to your MSN Messenger account if you had one.  Besides that difference the accounts are unified.  If you click on your "name" it will display the accounts associated with it.  The "name" displayed can be changed in the same capacity thats just a display name.